# How to combine manual insert and JPA Id generation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jboss-arquillian

I am running in-container tests with arquillian. I am prepopulating the database by adding an `import.sql` to the deployment. During the test I would like to create some more entities.

Unfortunately, this fails with a `PersistenceException`:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Unique index or
>   primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_BE ON
>   PUBLIC.KVS_MIPO_DOWNLOAD(ID)"

If I do not prepopulate the DB, or do not persist new entities, everything runs smoothly.

The id is the only unique field, so I strongly suspect that it must be the id generation using a sequence.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KVS_MIPO_DOWNLOAD")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class DownloadResource implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer id;
```

This entity is the superclass of another concrete entity, which does not add any unique attributes.

What can be done to be able to accomodate both possibilitiees - inserting manually and using a generated id?

Thank you

I am working with JPA 2 over Hibernate 4.0.1 in JBoss 7.1.1. The database is Sybase ASE 15.

**EDIT**: one workaround I have found so far is to set the Ids of the manually added entities high enough to avoid collisions. But this is not good enough for production - too many employees have write access to the db and may be tempted to add stuff manually. I would prefer the application to be robust enough not to die and explode in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative values for your manual ids. Hibernate shouldn't generate negative ones.

Optionally, use your own id generator that skips a particular range (or skips say numbers divisible by 7; some such scheme).

Sample ID generator:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class MyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {
        return 1; // TODO: Your scheme to create an Integer;
    }
}
```

To use this annotate as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "myid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "myid", strategy = "com.x.y.z.MyDGenerator")
public int getId() {
    return _id;
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know one could use negative numbers. Using a custom generator sounds reasonable too, I would either generate negative integers or count back from Integer.MAX_VALUE. Thank you, kabram

Answer (score 1):

You could also use UUIDs as id or, alternatively, a sequence. Manually added data could refer to the sequence as well.

Comment: +1. I am using a vanilla hibernate-generated sequence now. It simply starts at 1 and increments by 1, so I guess I will implement a custom generator like kabram proposed. UUID sounds good too though, I'll look into it. Thank you sorencito

Comment: I was referring to a database sequence. This decouples the id generation from the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Fastnate](http://fastnate.org) you can create the `import.sql` with the correct IDs, sufficient for your JPA model and your database.

For example you could create your entities this way:

```
EntitySqlGenerator generator = new EntitySqlGenerator(new FileWriter("import.sql"));
List<DownloadResource> resources = createDownloadResources();
generator.write(resources);
```

There are some more options to create the `import.sql`, but for a start that should be enough.

Fastnate has currently no special support for Sybase, but for most things the default dialect (H2) will work as well.

Comment: Sounds interesting. However simply dropping a tool name is only a good start ;) Could you add the relevant details of what and how to your answer, something minimally viable?

Comment: I hope the given example is enough. The topic is far to complex to describe all the options in a single answer.